# Bluetooth headset microphone not working after reconnect

Tags: bluetooth, microphone

I have a Bluetooth headset (HS70 BT) and I have this annoying issue where the microphone doesn't work when I reconnect it.

That is confusing so I'll recap :

- When I first paired it with my laptop, everything worked as expected.
- I then disconnected the headset (to plug it elsewhere or just shut it down to save battery)
- When I reconnect it, the microphone doesn't work, I can see the device listed as an output device in the sound preferences page, but not as an input device.

To be able to use the microphone again, I need to delete the device on the bluetooth dialog then put it back in pairing mode and repair the device.

That is quite annoying to say the least, what can I do to have the mic work every-time I connect my headset ?

Note : I'm using an up-to-date ubuntu 21.04.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you connected other Bluetooth devices and reconnected them later having the same problem? because if not it is probably your Bluetooth device.

Comment: I don't have other Bluetooth device to test. However I don't have this kind of problems when I pair this device with my work laptop using Windows 10, nor my android phone.